# iOS Post request, sending image Base64 encoded

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, uiimage, ios7.1

I was wondering if anybody could take a look at my code. It works when I try to send a simple string such as the line that is commented out. But if I try to send the Base64 encoded string something is not working.

```
UIImage *tempImage = _imageView.image;
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImage, 1);
NSString *base64String = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

NSData *data = [base64String dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://website.ca/uploadPhoto.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:data];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);
```

Comment: What does say the erorr (`err`) of the `NSURLConnection`? What does `responseData` look like?

Comment: responseData: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request Entity Too Large</h1>
The requested resource<br />/uploadPhoto.php<br />
does not allow request data with GET requests, or the amount of data provided in
the request exceeds the capacity limit.
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>

Comment: Try with a small image?

Comment: It works when I change the image compression to something small like .1

Comment: The responseData was saying it: `ata provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.`. Your file is too big. What's `_imageView.image` originally?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems I see here.

1. You are not setting the content type.
2. You are base 64 encoding the content without telling the server you are base 64 encoding the content.
3. Upload forms generally do not accept straight base 64 encoded jpeg images.

My guess is you will need to send this as [multipart/form-data](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867). Find out what fields need to be sent to the server, then you will be able to create the proper request.

There are several tutorials on using `NSURLRequest` to send multipart form data to a server. [Here](http://nthn.me/posts/2012/objc-multipart-forms.html) is the first one I found.